# What is the keyboard shortcut to move across workspaces?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gala

The key binding for moving an application to the workspace to the left or right does not appear to work. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left / Right</kbd> is listed as the appropriate binding in my settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> workspaces but it does not appear to work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

I just posted this question in case others had the same problem as me. Here is what I discovered.

The problem stems from <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> already being assigned as shortcuts. Install dconf-editor and navigate to org > gnome > desktop > wm > keybindings. From this you will see that move-to-workspace-left/right is assign both <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>. If you want to utilise the <kbd>Shift</kbd> option, then delete the assignments for move-to-monitor-left and move-to-monitor-right as it also uses the same keybinding. I assume these assignments were to move windows between multiple monitors, so if you have more than one monitor set up perhaps delete <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> from the keybindings for move-to-workspace-left and move-to-workspace-right, leaving <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> as your navigation options.

Comment: What if I want to 'flick' an application to the opposite monitor in a dual monitor setup, without changing workspaces? Is there a shortcut to do this?

Comment: There are `move-to-monitor-down` (and all other directions) keybindings for you to change there.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug in the keyboard settings plug, use <kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> to move an application.

Move to workspace 1: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
Move to workspace 2: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
Move to workspace 3: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>
...
Move to left <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>
Move to right <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The SUPER key plus any number key works for me on Luna. However, a second workspace needs to have an application open before a third becomes possible. The SUPER key plus down arrow reveals all open workspaces at the bottom of the screen, allowing one to choose between them with a mouse click if desired.