# Shift+Super+Right doesn't move current window right

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, workspace

I'm on elementary OS Freya.

On Luna, one could use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to move a window from this workspace to the next workspace.

In Freya, I've noticed that when I have multiple monitors connected, the shortcut simply moves a window from one screen to the next screen to the right. Without multiple monitors connected, the shortcut doesn't work, the window stays on the current workspace.

My keyboard shortcut settings are pretty standard:

[image]

Has this functionality changed in Freya? Interestingly enough, I can do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and it works okay if I'm not on the first workspace.

Comment: try to re-assign the shortcut, Its working fine on my system.

Answer (score 6):

The keys to do this in Loki are <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know for Freya but in Loki these shortcuts have effectively been changed to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> and they are working all right.

Cf., [What is the keyboard shortcut to move across workspaces?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-across-workspaces)

Comment: In fact, I have Freya and I have it right as in the question, however Alt+Super+Left/Right work, but Shift-Super-Left/Right doesn't